# Google Foobar challenge "Find the access codes"

Tags: python, list

### SOLVED

**I was sorting the list when in reality the prompt was asking for the order in which the numbers were given. Not going to delete the post in case someone else makes the same mistake.**

I would like to preface this by saying that I have already read over other answers to this conundrum, but to no avail. I even tried copying the provided solutions, just to see if they actually worked, and they failed more test cases than the code I used.

### Original Prompt

> "Write a function answer(l) that takes a list of positive integers l and counts the number of "lucky triples" of (li, lj, lk) where the list indices meet the requirement i < j < k. The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive. The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive. The answer fits within a signed 32-bit integer. Some of the lists are purposely generated without any access codes to throw off spies, so if no triples are found, return 0.
>
> A "lucky triple" is a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4).
>
> For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] has the triples: [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], making the answer 3 total."

At this point, I'm not even asking for a solution so I can pass to the next level, because I would feel that I am cheating at that point, however, I have no idea *why* I am failing test cases 3-5 (and obviously the test cases aren't publicly available, but I'm just asking if anyone can find flaws in my programming).

Like I'm sure most people did, I began by creating a triple for-loop that iterated over every possible "triple," but seeing as it was O(n^3), it took too long. I am, however, using that as a "base solution" for my code to compare answers to more complicated cases.

### My code (in python)

I apologize if the code is a bit messy, but I am new to python, and mainly did this challenge for the learning opportunity, and just to work my brain.

The function takes a list, l, and then I sort it into descending order. I then create a list which I initialize all values to 0. For the first while-loop set, I am counting the amount of "doubles" where l[y] divides l[x] evenly, then count the amount of factors that l[x] has. I.e if there were a list [1,2,3,4] then this loop checks [3%2] , [3%1], [2%1].

The next while-loop set checks the first 2 numbers ([4%3] , [4%2] , [3%2]). Both of these loops are verified in my (local) code with print statements, and those are the operations occurring. If the mod in the second while set is true, then it increments the counter by the amount of factors that the 'Y' value had (in this case, only [4%2] is true and then it would go to the l_count list and increment the count variable by the value in the array that corresponds to 2. In this case, it is 1, because the only true case for the number "2" in the first while loop is [2%1]). I would have included comments in my code, but I did not think I would be having this issue in the first place.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
l.sort()
l = l[::-1]

length = len(l)

count = 0

l_count = []
for x in range(len(l)):
    l_count.append(0)

x = 1
while x < (length - 1):
    y = x + 1
    while y < length:
        if l[x] % l[y] == 0:
            l_count[x] = l_count[x] + 1
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1

x = 0
while x < (length - 2):
    y = x + 1
    while y < (length - 1):
        if l[x] % l[y] == 0:
            count = count + l_count[y]
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1

return count
```

Comment: Just found on another page that the following constraint must hold as well for a "lucky number":  li divides lj and lj divides lk

Comment: Shoot, I forgot to include that above. Thanks. Adding to the original post.

Comment: Can you tell in what way you and the other solutions are "failing"? Wrong result? Too slow? Crash? What?

Comment: @StefanPochmann with the original triple for-loop solution, it would say "time-limit exceeded." Since I made my solution run in O(n^2) time instead of O(n^3) time, all it is saying is
"foobar:~/find_the_access_codes *namehidden*$ verify solution.py
Verifying solution...
Test 1 passed!
Test 2 passed!
Test 3 failed.
Test 4 failed.
Test 5 failed."

Comment: Also, that is the original prompt, not my command. Sorry for the confusion, I am new here.

Comment: I have done that, as well as using other test cases I have found online. I cannot think of a very efficient way of generating test cases, testing them in both my [relatively] efficient method, and the inefficient method, or what kind of lists may lead to a weird "special case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you do is already a mistake: Sorting. That'll make you report that [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] has three such triples (same as the example) when in reality it doesn't have any.

(Given that you pass two of five tests, I can imagine this is your only mistake. Maybe those tests are already sorted so you're not messing those up.)

Comment: Oh my gosh. I guess I was misunderstanding the prompt. When it says "where the list indices meet the requirement i < j < k" I was interpreting that as "l[i] < l[j] < l[k]"   simply commenting out the sort function caused me to pass all cases. You just ended a 4 day headache streak, and I can't thank you enough :)